# generate SQL queries out of CSV table

Tags: sql, shell, csv

Good morning, 
I have a CSV file that contains in the first line the column of my tables and the rest is data. Something like that

```
FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3
data1,data2,data3 
data1,data2,data3
```

Now I have been trying to write a script that will return the following output and can be used for more than once.

```
INSERT INTO tablename (FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3) VALUES
   (data1,data2,data3)
INSERT INTO tablename (FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3) VALUES
   (data1,data2,data3)
INSERT INTO tablename (FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3) VALUES
   (data1,data2,data3)
```

That's what I have so far but it does not return the correct output.

```
firstline=$(printf '%s\n' 1p d wq | ed -s file.csv )
cat file.csv | while read line
do
    field1=$(echo "$line" | cut -d "," -f1)
    field2=$(echo "$line" | cut -d "," -f2)
    field3=$(echo "$line" | cut -d "," -f3)

    echo "INSERT INTO tablename ($firstline) VALUES ($fields1 $field2 $field3) ">prova.csv
done
```

```
) VALUES (  15blename (data1,1,1
```

I am not sure I can use the variable `$firstline` inside the while loop... but I don't understand why it doesn't print me the insert into and the correct parenthesis.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: 
I have a new problem: SQL assistant does not allow me to insert values that are not enclosed with "'" so my question is how do I edit the script to make it look like this :

- INSERT INTO tablename (columns) VALUES ('data1','data2','data3') ">prova.csv

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using awk:

```
awk 'NR==1{x=$0;next} {printf "INSERT INTO tablename (%s) VALUES (%s)\n",x,$0}' file
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried again and it works but I still get the same results : )VALUES ( 1, 2, 3 . The parentheses are not correct and the insert into is not considered I don't understand why

Comment: @Marco Does your input file have DOS line endings? If yes, fix it by `dos2unix file` command

Comment: EDIT: I have a new problem: SQL assistant does not allow me to insert values that are not enclosed with "'" so my question is how do I edit the script to make it look like this :

INSERT INTO tablename (columns) VALUES ('data1','data2','data3') ">prova.csv

Comment: @Marco `awk 'NR==1{x=$0;next} {gsub(/,/,"\47,\47");printf "INSERT INTO tablename (%s) VALUES (\47%s\47)\n",x,$0}' file`